# Наталия или Наталья

Tags: недопустимая-метка, ономастика

Как правильно писать "Наталия" или "Наталья"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильны обе формы имени, хотя форма "Наталия" считается более старой и, так сказать, классической. Точно также, как равноценны имена Максим и Максимилиан или Борис и Борислав. Все зависит от того, как записано у человека в документах.

Answer (score 1):

Наталия, Мария, София — книжные, а Наталья, Марья, Софья - просторечные.